# Which SSL-certificate can insure a secure TCP-connection between C# listener on Amazon Lightsail instance and iOS app?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, websocket, tcp

I created a simple .NET Core Console application on C# which uses TcpListener to accept connections on a specific port and return an answer.

I bought an **AWS Lightsail** instance and deploy my server application manually via RDP. The instance has a static IP-address and a domain name like `ec2-<IP>.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` (as I discovered via reverse DNS lookup). The client is an iOS application and it needs a secure TCP connection to transfer data to server and vice versa. iOS app is not working with my self-signed certificate - it needs to use **certificate from trusted CA**, so the question is: where I can get the trusted SSL-certificate for Amazon Lightsail instance mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I created a package to help with sockets and iOS using Obj-C. Also included is a very good resource for creating a certificate that will work. You will actually probably need to create a certificate authority, and intermediate certificate authority, and server/client certificates, check out the link:

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets/tree/master